# what is laravel render() method for?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I didn't deal with render method yet !!
is it for blade template ?
I have to pass dynamic data in blade.php file dynamically.

Comment: Go to: https://laravel.com/docs/ - Search for "render" in the search field and you will get your answer. Laravel's documentation is quite extensive so you should check there first.

Comment: would need to know what you are calling the `render` method on, or in what context.

Comment: Please try to take a little time to take a look at the docs before posting a question here it will be worth your while and also will not waste your time then on posting your question here then..! :D

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for your tips. Your are the most genius person I have ever seen in this world. Thanks you so much. I found many details searching on Laravel docs.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Given that you've tagged the question with Blade, I'll assume you mean render inside Laravel's View class.

`Illuminate\View\View::render()` returns the string contents of the view. It is also used inside the class' `__toString()` method which allows you to echo a  View object.

```
// example.blade.php
Hello, World!

// SomeController.php
$view = view('example');
echo $view->render(); // Hello, World!
echo $view;  // Hello, World!
```

Laravel typically handles this for you, I.e. calls render or uses the object as a string when necessary.

Blade's @include('viewname') directive will load the view file and call the render method behind the scenes for example.

You may use it yourself when you want to get the compiled view to perform some subsequent action. Occasionally I have called render explicitly rather than to string if the view itself is causing an exception and in PHP explains

> Fatal error: Method a::__toString() must not throw an exception in /index.php on line 12

Calling render() in the above case gives a more useful error message.

Answer (score 17):

`Render()`, when applied to a view, will generate the corresponding raw html and store the result in a variable.

Typical reasons for which I use render are:

When converting pages to pdf (ex. using dompdf, pass this into `loadhtml()`), returning HTML content to ajax calls

Comment: I'm trying to send $view->render() to pdf. The problem is i have <a href that have [] in them, which get converted with render().  Know what I can do to clear that up?

Answer (score 9):

You can get php blade file with **passing** **dynamic** value in a **string** form

Like this

**Blade**

```
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="{{$url}}/assets/images/favicon/apple-icon-60x60.png">
```

**Controller**

```
$html = view('User::html-file',['url'=>'https://stackoverflow.com'])->render();
```

**O/P**

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="https://stackoverflow.com/assets/images/favicon/apple-icon-60x60.png">\r\n
```

Answer (score 0):

0pposed to `->render()` when using DomPDF, you can also use `->toHtml()`:

###### `$pdf->loadHtml(\view('folderX.bladeY', $data)->toHtml());`

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, the render() method is used to render a view and return its contents as a string. It is often used when you need to generate a view and include its contents in an email, PDF document, or other types of output.

For example, you might use the render() method to generate the contents of a PDF invoice by rendering an invoice template view and then passing the rendered contents to a PDF generator library.

Here's an example of using the render() method to return the contents of a view as a string:

**$content = view('my-view')->render();**