# Triple quotes and start and end of dumped file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a blade file that looks like this, just simple text on two lines:

```
xyz
hello
```

But when I die and dump the blade file:

```
$view = view('my-view')->render();
```

I get this:

```
"""
xyz\n
hello
"""
```

Where are these quotes coming from?

Comment: Weird one! I've only encountered triple quotes in cucumber-syntax.

Comment: how do you die and dump, provide some code

Comment: just use dd(); to die and dump

Answer (score 0):

They are surely coming from dd, try doing `echo $view;`

Comment: I don't think so, when I don't dd, and return the view as a response with a plain text content type, the .txt file that downloads has white space at the start of it.

Comment: reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772786/what-is-laravel-render-method-for