# What does $this->render in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hi i want to know what does `$this->render` in Laravel. I am using Laravel 4.2

```
return $this->render('user.home.index', [],
            ['title' => $this->setTitle(trans('global.home'))]
        );
```

I am not able to find where `user/home/index` is located

Comment: Open the app/view folder where you may found user folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is laravel render() method for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772786/what-is-laravel-render-method-for)

Answer (score 1):

`$this->render` used to render view files present in `app/views` directory.

And `user/home/index` indicates the view file `index.blade.php` present in `app/views/user/home` directory.

Answer (score 0):

$this->render returns the string contents of the view.

// demo.blade.php

My name is John doe.

// DemoController.php

$view = view('demo');
echo $view->render(); // My name is John doe.