# How to return the view in ajax in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

We are using ajax to call the controller in Laravel. Like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "url/url/",
  data: {
    _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
    action: 'get-some-view',
    data: {}
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $("#container").html(data.html);
  }
});
```

We are hoping to do something like this on the controller:

```
return response()->json( [ 'code' => 0, 'data' => view('viewname')->with('foo ', $foo ), 'msg' => 'YEH!' ] , 200);
```

But the response we are getting is

```
Object { code: 0, data: {}, msg: "YEH" }
```

Our expected output is the HTML generated on view. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to render the view to get the HTML. Should be -

```
view('viewname')->with('foo ', $foo )->render()
```

[SO render() description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772786/what-is-laravel-render-method-for)

Answer (score 2):

The render() method will give you the raw HTML.

Check out the method here [View](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/View/View.php#L87)

Answer (score 1):

view() function just creates an instance of the View class. For rendering HTML string use render() function.

```
$data = view('viewname')->with('foo', $foo)->render();
return response()->json( [ 'code' => 0, 'data' => $data, 'msg' => 'YEH!' ] , 200);
```