# What is the use of view()->render()?

Tags: php, laravel

So, currently for sending dynamic e-mails I am using blade by making the body of the email `view('email.blade.php)`

This works fine. I know that there is a **->render()** function you can use on **view()** that returns the HTML as a string. What is the point of this? I see the same behaviour without using **->render()**

Comment: What if you need to __log__ contents of letter to database?

Comment: @u_mulder This is essentially what I already do. My e-mails are sent by using an email table that I have a C# script watching that sends the e-mails, so view('email.blade.php') is returning the HTML by default, without render()

Comment: see this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772786/what-is-laravel-render-method-for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772786/what-is-laravel-render-method-for)

Comment: If the method exist, that doesn't mean you need to use it. When Laravel is done with all the processing - it needs to output the data as HTML. This is where `render()` kicks in because Laravel uses `echo` to send data back to web server. Therefore, what  it does is (dumbed down) `echo view('name')->render()`.

Comment: @UnniKS I am already aware of what the render function does, I just don't understand why it exists when it seems to be called automatically anyway.

Comment: Useful when you want to return a view as part of an ajax request, you will send the view as string and use Javascript to render in DOM..

Comment: @AkramWahid My point is. Doing view() is the same as doing view()->render(), you can achieve the same thing you are on about and send a string back to an AJAX call without using render()

Comment: @iJamesPHP2, render is a view factory method, it help you take the view contents into a variable as string and helps you with further processing. You can't take the processed view string into a variable with just view method...

Comment: @AkramWahid Yes you can. $viewStr = view('view') will store it in a string

Comment: You are correct, this is basically you are making a view that is to be returned to the browser and store the object in a variable called $viewStr as in your example. Suppose you want to convert that object to its string representation which is basically the contents of the view with all the dynamic data injected. This can be done using the render method on the view object to return the same content.

Comment: @AkramWahid What's returned to the browser is its string representation. view(x) and view(x)->render() are the exact same, this is my point

Comment: @AkramWahid If you had read the comments, I already use view(x) to store the rendered HTML in a database not view(x)->render(). I'm not arguing, just interested, I'd prefer someone who actually understands the framework and knows the answer to my question to input on this, not you

Answer (score -2):

It depends on what you want to do with it. You can use it to convert pages to PDF using some sort of library like [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) or return the view content within a HTTP request.